# How to match only first occurrence of space at line

Tags: java, regex

I am getting stuck on maybe really simple step.

I have line with following text `[[StandardsEnterprise GXS Enterprise]]`
and want to replace first space by pipe ("|")
Cannot find the regex for select only of the space.

Or, maybe the problem is with the Java code. 
I am using java within SAG WebMethods with following:

```
    IDataCursor pipelineCursor = pipeline.getCursor();
    String regex = IDataUtil.getString(pipelineCursor, "regex");
    String input = IDataUtil.getString(pipelineCursor, "input");
    String replacement = IDataUtil.getString(pipelineCursor, "replacement");
    pipelineCursor.destroy();

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    String output = matcher.replaceAll(replacement);

    ....
```

Isn't there the problem with `.replaceAll` method? Isn't apply the regex repeatedly on the input string?

Have you simple advice for me?

Many thanks
Reddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have to replace once the space by pipe only.

Using regex it is a really simple thing like this:

```
\s+
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/sS7uX5/1)**

Depending on the language you are using, you can do...

PHP

```
textpop-up
$re = "/\\s+/"; 
$str = "[[StandardsEnterprise GXS Enterprise]]"; 
$subst = '|'; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str, 1);
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var re = /\s+/; 
var str = '[[StandardsEnterprise GXS Enterprise]]';
var subst = '|'; 

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

PYTHON

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'\s+')
test_str = u"[[StandardsEnterprise GXS Enterprise]]"
subst = u"|"

result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```

JAVA

```
String result = "[[StandardsEnterprise GXS Enterprise]]".replaceFirst("\\s+", "|");
System.out.println(result);
// Prints:
// [[StandardsEnterprise|GXS Enterprise]]
```

Comment: Hello Fede, thank you so much for the reply. I am using Java service. I will specify more the request.